# How to compute density functions of $E(Y_1|Y_2)$

Tags: probability-theory

Good afternoon. I've trying to do some exercises. Here is one that I can't continue with.

Here is the question: "Find the density functions of $E(Y_1|Y_2)$". My function that I got is $f(y_1,y_2)=\exp(-y_2)$ where $0\leq y_1 \leq y_2$.

My own idea is that I need to find the $\textit{conditional expectation}$ which I did, but then I can't continue from here.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional expectation $E(Y_1|Y_2)$ is a function of $Y_2$ that you have presumably figured out.  Call it $g$, so $E(Y_1|Y_2)=g(Y_2)$.  Since $Y_2$ is a random variable whose distribution you presumably know, you should be able to work out the distribution of the random variable $g(Y_2)$.

Comment: So in this case, $g(Y_2)=\frac{y}{2}$ and according to a definition in my text, I need to integrate this function with my previuous bounds?

Comment: I like to do these kinds of problems step-by-step.  What is the density function  (the marginal density function)  of $Y_2$?    Once you know that you can work out the density function for  $Y_2/2$.

Comment: Sorry, typo. $g(Y_2)=\frac{y_2}{2}$. Note that I computed $E(Y_1|Y_2=y_2)=\frac{y_2}{2}$. I'm not sure that I understand you comment very well.

Comment: @Joey To reiterate, $E(Y_1\mid Y_2=y_2)=\frac{y_2}{2}$ is a real number; $E(Y_1\mid Y_2)=\frac{Y_2}{2}$ is a random variable whose distribution you are asked to find.